# Android studio Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-manifest

After i have created my own appplication class:

```
package com.example.bezzabarovaa.myapplication;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Created by bezzabarovaa on 04.08.2017.
 */

public class app extends Application {
public static Context context;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

}
```

and have changed manifest.xml (changed application to app class)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bezzabarovaa.myapplication">

<app
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label = "@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</app>
```

I`ve got a message Error running Unnamed: Default Activity not found

If I will change my class`app` back to `application` in manifest.xml - everything  is ok.
Where is a problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Where's your Activity?

Comment: what makes you think you can change the tag name and it won't break?

Comment: You can't change the tag names! You should use `<application android:name=".app">` and please follow the Java guidelines, where a class name should be CamelCase (not app, but App in your case).

Answer (score 8):

This `<app` is supposed to be `<application` you specify your custom app in here:

```
<application android:name=".app" ...
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) the name section says:

> The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for
>   the application. When the application process is started, this class
>   is instantiated before any of the application's components. The
>   subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence
>   of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.

Full example (with your code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bezzabarovaa.myapplication">

<application
    android:name=".app"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label = "@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved by clicking the "Sync project with gradle files"

Answer (score 1):

Use below code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bezzabarovaa.myapplication">

<application
    android:name=".app"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label = "@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How does this code solve the asker's problem? He already says he knows it works if he changes it back to `<application>`. That's exactly what you've recommended here.

Comment: @CodyGray; The asker's code does not include `android:name=".app"` part while this (and the other answer) does

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a while ago, after changing my default activity to another.

What solved it was invalidate caches and restart Android Studio:

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

and then clicking on `Invalidate and Restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your manifest application tag

```
<application
    android:name=".app"
    ...
     </application>
```

Comment: How does this code solve the asker's problem? He already says he knows it works if he changes it back to `<application>`. That's exactly what you've recommended here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Android Studio not to complain by going to the "Edit Configurations" menu (tap "Shift" three times, type "Edit Configurations"), then change Launch Options > Launch to "Nothing".

I'll probably add a generic activity containing instructions, just to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceScanActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceControlActivity" />

        <service android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.BluetoothLeService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: At least give some definition to your answer, it would be confusing to leave code without description.

Comment: check whether is " <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />" in intent-filter

Comment: As it currently stands, this is a poor quality answer. Please provide an explanation of the code, and maybe emphasize the specific problem you solved.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the very same issue by following steps

Close Android Studio

deleting from :

C:\Users\your user name.android/log and gradle folder

C:\Users\your user name.gradle

from C:\Users[your user name]

Restart Computer and run Android studio (it Will take some time to rebuild)